# I need to change the date format using php

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

Hi I have looked at a question already posted about this and tried to adapt my code to do a simlar thing. Basicly I have a field in my mysql database that has the date in this format yyyy-dd-mm i need to the format to be dd-mm-yyyy. Currently my code is getting stuck on the line `echo "<td><strong> ("d/m/y",". $row['date'] .")</strong></td>";` and reads this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'. Not sure how to fix this any ideas I would be greatful.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbGigs WHERE CURDATE() < date ORDER BY date");

echo "<table class=\"gigs\">
<tr>
<th>Venue</th>
<th>Town</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><strong>" . $row['venue'] . "</strong></td>";
  echo "<td><strong>" . $row['town'] . "</strong></td>";
  echo "<td><strong> ("d/m/y",". $row['date'] .")</strong></td>";
  echo "<td><strong>" . $row['time'] . "</strong></td>";
  echo "<td><strong>" . $row['status'] . "</strong></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 7):

First things first

```
  echo "<td><strong> ("d/m/y",". $row['date'] .")</strong></td>";
```

This line looks wrong; I suspect it ought to read something like

```
  echo "<td><strong>" . date( "d/m/y", $row['date'] ) . "</strong></td>";
```

Note the missing function call and concatenation operators. Incidentally, while this is syntactically correct (so far as I can see), it may not do what you're looking for, depending upon what `$row['date']` actually contains - it needs to be a Unix timestamp for `date()` to grok it properly.

To obtain the date as a Unix timestamp, you can use the MySQL function [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) when selecting the date, e.g.

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS date_ts FROM ...
```

You can then access `$row['date_ts']` as normal, and pass it into the `date()` function for formatting. Alternatively, you can use something like [`strtotime()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to parse the current value being returned in order to get a timestamp from that.

A further alternative is to have MySQL format the date on your behalf, using its [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function; again, you can access this value returned from the query and print it out.

Comment: Yes you are correct I doesn't do what I want haha. The date stored in that that field date is a mysql date field and asks for the date in the format yyyy-dd-mm which I don't think is very easy for the user to understand when viewed on a webpage. Would you know how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer with a few ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like:

```
echo "<td><strong>".date("d/m/y", strtotime($row['date']))."</strong></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the [`date` function](http://docs.php.net/date):

```
echo "<td><strong>".date("d/m/y", $row['date'])."</strong></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT dte FROM vtable');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
print date('d M Y', strtotime($row['dte']));
```