# How to convert a mysql datetime in PHP to m/d/y format?

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to convert a mysql DATETIME into this format m/d/y but the code below is not working, returns 12/31/1969 instead can someone show me how to do this?

```
$fromMYSQL = '2007-10-17 21:46:59'; //this is the result from mysql DATETIME field
echo date("m/d/Y", $fromMYSQL);
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think what you really want is this:

```
$fromMYSQL = '2007-10-17 21:46:59';
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($fromMYSQL));
```

The second argument of date is a timestamp and I think what is happening is PHP sees your string as a -1 timestamp... thus 12/31/1969.

So, to get a timestamp from the string version of the date, you use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime)

Comment: Change the format string to "m/d/Y" and I will upvote. He wants 4 digit year.

Comment: Great. Works. Easy to implement.

Answer (score 7):

SQL:

```
SELECT whatever, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) date FROM table WHERE whatever
```

PHP:

```
date('m/d/Y', $result['date']);
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to convert the dateformat direct in your Querystring:

```
$TimeFormat = "%m/%d/%Y";  // your pref. Format

$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DateCol , '" . $TimeFormat . "') as ConvertDate FROM tblTest";
```

Otherwise you can modify this function to your needs:

```
function format_date($original, $format) {
    if (empty($original)) {
        $original = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
    $original = ereg_replace("30 Dez 1899", "30-01-1973", $original);
    $format = ($format=='date' ? "%m-%d-%Y" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='germandate' ? "%d.%m.%y" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='germandaydate' ? "%A, %d.%m.%Y" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='germantime' ? "%H:%M" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='germandatetime' ? "%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='datetime' ? "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='mysql-date' ? "%Y-%m-%d" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='mysql-datetime' ? "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='mssql-date' ? "%Y%m%d" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='mssql-datetime' ? "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S" : $format);
    $format = ($format=='Ymd' ? "%Y-%m-%d" : $format);
    return !empty($original) ? strftime($format, strtotime($original)) : "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a capital `Y` int the date format string. the lowercase `y` gives a two digit year and the upper case 'Y' give a four digit year.

```
$fromMYSQL = '2007-10-17 21:46:59';
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($fromMYSQL));
```

[PHP Manual Page For date](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) may be of some assistance.

Comment: you are correct for getting a 4 digit year however that doesn't help with my problem of not showing the correct date, shows 12/31/1969

Comment: Answer updated. `strtotime` should parse the time from MySql.

Answer (score 2):

I covered this in my answer to h[ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/499014/i-need-to-change-the-date-format-using-php/499021#499021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499014/i-need-to-change-the-date-format-using-php/499021#499021) - basically, `date()` expects a Unix timestamp from which it calculates the date/time and formats that. You're passing in a string which comes from the MySQL query result, which probably gets mangled by PHP's duck typing into something that looks like a Unix timestamp, but makes no sense.

I explain a couple of approaches to dealing with date columns in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1) You need a capital Y

2) You need a correct date type.

Try

```
$fromMYSQL = date_create  ('2007-10-17 21:46:59');    
echo date("m/d/Y", $fromMYSQL);
```

Oops, strtotime is the right conversion to a timestamp. date_create returns a DateTime object.